# Calculate intersecting areas for different groups of Multipolygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection

I have two polygon vector layers in QGIS: black buffers and land-use.

I want to calculate the areas of the black polygons that fall within each of the different land-use classes (these are colour coded according to a column in the attribute table).

I know how to do this if I were to convert one land-use class at a time into a polygon, but given there are 10+ land uses, I was wondering if there was a quicker way?

[image]

Comment: I am confused: Are those dots (aka points), or are they circles?

Comment: Hi, these were originally points that have been dissolved to give a single polygon.

Comment: Points can't be polygons.

Comment: Oops, missed out a step. They were points, then a buffer was placed around them, then this buffer area was dissolved = the black visible in the image.

Comment: And you need the area of each landuse category for the whole dissolved area?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Trying to calculate the areas for each land-use category that intersects the black dissolved area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a process of three steps:

1. Run `intersection`: The first input layer are you black circles, the second one is your landuse (the whole layer). This gives you a layer with the extent of the circles and the properties and division into categories of the landuse data.
2. Run `dissolve` based on the landuse.
3. Use the `field calculator` to calculate the `$area` of the dissolved layer.